# Connect private EC2 instances using ssh via public instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, private, public

I have a few EC2 instances.
Only one instance is accessible (ssh port 22) from the Internet.
I want to connect to the others EC2 instances in ssh through the first one.

The public key is set on all EC2 instance.
I enable the forward agent (.ssh/config) for my first instance:

```
Host my-first-instance
  ForwardAgent yes
```

I thought it was enough but when I connect to the first instance and try to connect to another one (ssh my-second-instance-private-IP), I have a "permission denied". They both use the same user.

I use the same ssh key to access Github from the first instance and it works (so the ForwardAgent works as well).

I don't want to use a VPC feature.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Jeremy

Comment: "I don't want to use a VPC feature." why? The following might be helpful: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3N8GFK85UN1G6/Securely-connect-to-Linux-instances-running-in-a-private-Amazon-VPC

Comment: I read that article and it's what I've done at first. But it still doesn't work. And I don't understand why as the access to Github is working from first instance with the same key trusted in second instance. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had done similar thing earlier by changing the ip-tables of the public instance so that I can connect to different private instances by connecting on different ports. Here is the link to blog that I wrote to explain the same. Hope it helps

http://cloudpages.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/ssh-to-an-instance-in-private-subnet/

Bests,
Himanshu

Comment: I was trying to avoid configuring more things in the VPC, but may be is the more flexible and state-of-the-art way... Thanks.

Comment: I'll appreciate if you can thumbs-up my answer in case it helped ;)

Comment: My low reputation doesn't allow me to upvote your answer :-) And I'm still stuck with my forward-agent problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting permission denied probably because you may not have pub keys of your jump server in your ec2 server's authorized_keys. please do the following -

1. ssh to the 1st ec2 instance.
2. generate public and private key pair using keygen.
3. put the content of the public key (default is .ssh/id_rsa.pub (in case you are 
   using rsa)) in other ec2 instance's .ssh/authorized_keys.

Now check again.

Comment: I was more looking for a way to not generated another key pair. I thought I could use only one key pair which is trusted (authorized_keys) in both instances, but connect to the second instance only through the first one.